# Restore SQL db?

Tags: sql-server, restore

I have a small db that I need to restore back in time. Meaning I have the db running now, but some data has been overwritten, so I need to restore a version from last night for instance.

But when I try to "Task > Restore > Database" I select the same db in both source and destination. I get an error "Cannot open the backup device... Operating system error 2(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It may sound harsh, but what you did wrong happened when you first created the backup: you failed to test the restore process.  If you don't know how to restore your backups, you don't have backups.

Comment: This sounds like MSSQL but you might want to clarify

Comment: @MarkHenderson Yeah, sorry. It is MSSQL.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL Server is having a problem finding or accessing the backup file on the file system.  Does the file exist in the location that is shown in the UI?

Answer (score 1):

Try running SQL Server Management Studio "As Administrator". This is usually a permissions related issue.

Comment: Tried it, dident help :-(

Comment: So you ran the program as Admin? Are you also making sure that the SQL user has the correct permissions? Like SA? Check that as well.